# Nginx(Django) ImportError: cannot import name celeryd

Tags: python, django, nginx, celery, celerybeat

I tested my project in my local machine, and it worked fine. But after uploading to a remote server(CentOS), I cannot execute celerybeat.

Here is my command.
`python manage.py celeryd --events --loglevel=INFO -c 5 --settings=[settings-directory].production`

This command works in the local machine(with *--settings=[settings-directory].local*), but in the remote server, `ImportError: cannot import name celeryd` occured.

Setting about celery is in *base.py*. *local.py* and *production.py* import the file. In *production.py*, there are just DEBUG, static, database settings.

I can import *djcelery* and *celery* in shell of the remote machine.

How could I solve this?

--

I think this is a version problem.. I'm reading about celery3.1

Comment: Where did you get the command? [django-celery docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery) say to start beat with `python manage.py celery beat`.

Comment: @Lycha http://mechanicalgirl.com/post/scheduling-periodic-tasks-celery-233-and-django-14/ from here... I followed these steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I used different version of Django in my remote server.

In Celery 3.1, there is no command named celeryd.